# update a table row from CTE

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable `@xml` as follows :

```
<root>
    <row USER_KEY="1" USER_NAME="test" USER_ID="12345" USER_STATUS=" " USER_GENDER="F" />
</root>
```

So in my stored procedure I have to read this xml and update the row of the `tbl_USER` table based on `USER_KEY` from xml.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(Name nvarchar(250),
                  Value nvarchar(250));

Insert Into #tbl(Name, Value)
   select 
       T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
       T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')
   from 
       @XML.nodes('/root/row/@*') as T(N)
```

Now I need to update the `tbl_user` with these values. Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: You can read xml parameters using OPENXML

This might help -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244796/stored-procedure-passing-a-parameter-as-xml-and-reading-the-data

Comment: Can you add the table structure of `tbl_user` with some sample data and what the result should be after the update?

Comment: Is your XML only ever going to have a single entry of type `<row>`? Otherwise, you'll need to find out how to associate the various values with a given `<row>`...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (I'm just *guessing* what the columns in your `tbl_user` table are called, you didn't provide that info - so you'll need to adapt that as needed):

```
;WITH UpdateCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        UserKey = (SELECT Value FROM #tbl WHERE Name = 'USER_KEY'),
        UserName = (SELECT Value FROM #tbl WHERE Name = 'USER_NAME'),
        UserID = (SELECT Value FROM #tbl WHERE Name = 'USER_ID'),
        UserStatus = (SELECT Value FROM #tbl WHERE Name = 'USER_Status'),
        UserGender = (SELECT Value FROM #tbl WHERE Name = 'USER_Gender')
    FROM #tbl
)
UPDATE dbo.tbl_Users
SET UserName = cte.UserName,
    UserID = cte.UserID,
    Status = cte.UserStatus,
    Gender = cte.UserGender
FROM dbo.Users u
INNER JOIN UpdateCTE cte ON u.UserKey = cte.UserKey
```

Basically, I create a CTE (Common Table Expression) based on your temporary table, and I select out the values stored in it as columns. Based on that CTE, I can then use a regular T-SQL `UPDATE` statement to update the `tbl_Users` table based on those temporary values.

This will work in SQL Server **2005** and newer (again: you didn't provide that info in your question)

Alternatively, you don't necessarily need a temporary table here, I think. You could use the CTE to directly "fish out" the attributes from the XML variable, and then use them to update your `tbl_Users` table - something like this:

```
;WITH UpdateCTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
        UserKey = T.N.value('@USER_KEY', 'INT'),
        UserName = T.N.value('@USER_NAME', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        UserID = T.N.value('@USER_ID', 'INT'),
        UserStatus = T.N.value('@USER_STATUS', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        UserGender = T.N.value('@USER_GENDER', 'CHAR(1)')
   FROM
       @XML.nodes('/root/row') as T(N)
)
UPDATE dbo.tbl_Users
SET UserName = cte.UserName,
    UserID = cte.UserID,
    Status = cte.UserStatus,
    Gender = cte.UserGender
FROM dbo.Users u
INNER JOIN UpdateCTE cte ON u.UserKey = cte.UserKey
```

Again: adapt the column names (and the types of the XQuery `.value()` calls) as needed - I am just *guessing* here....